# compilation error on @js.native when added @js.native annotation to a trait on scalajs

Tags: scala.js

It appears like `@js.native` is not identified by my compiler.  In general `scalajs` compiles to me in the project.

[link to file](https://github.com/avidanyum/scalajs-example/blob/master/src/main/scala/example/Funnel.scala) (and its including project in github where it fails).

source of the file that fails on `@js.native`

```
package example

import scala.scalajs.js
import js.annotation._

@js.native // sbt won't compile this native not found how to fix?
trait Funnel {

}
```

yields:

> Funnel.scala:8: type native is not a member of package
>   scala.scalajs.js [error] @js.native [error]     ^ [error] one error
>   found

sbt for reference:

```
import com.lihaoyi.workbench.Plugin._

enablePlugins(ScalaJSPlugin)

workbenchSettings

name := "Example"

version := "0.1-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.11.5"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scala-js" %%% "scalajs-dom" % "0.8.0",
  "com.lihaoyi" %%% "scalatags" % "0.5.4"
)

jsDependencies += "org.webjars" % "d3js" % "3.5.12" / "d3.js"

jsDependencies += ProvidedJS / "d3-funnel.js"

bootSnippet := "example.ScalaJSExample().main(document.getElementById('canvas'));"

updateBrowsers <<= updateBrowsers.triggeredBy(fastOptJS in Compile)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are running scala.js 0.6.1. Try to upgrade your version to >= 0.6.5